# Create new object dynamically

Tags: javascript, oop

Is there a way of adding an object without having to declare a const?

```
function Car (make, color) {
    this.make = make,
    this.color = color,  
    this.greet = function () {
        console.log(`The make is ${this.make} and color is ${this.color}`);
  };
}

const newObject = "Toyota"

const ford = new Car("Ford", "blue")
ford.greet();``

const vauxhall = new Car("Vauxhall", "green")
vauxhall.greet();
```

I thought I may be able to have:

```
const newObject = "Toyota"
```

Then add Toyota in place of ford or vauxhall.

Comment: You ask *"without having to declare a const"* and then give an example where a const `newObject` is defined. You lost me. What do you want?

Comment: I want to create a new Car object as const ford = new Car("Ford", "blue") but somehow pass a name dynamically so ford can be set in another variable. Otherwise I have to make a const for each object I add

Comment: OK, but then where do you get those dynamic names from? Do you have an array with names? And what about the colors? Where do they come from?

Comment: Not sure at the moment. Just playing around with objects and the new keyword. Thought I maybe able to pass a variable so I do not need to make a new const each time I want to add an object to Car. So use a function where ford is passed as a variable and create a NEW CAR object that way

Comment: But you already have such a function: the constructor! Why would you wrap the constructor in *another* function that again takes the brand of the car as argument, just to call `new Car` with it? You don't gain anything. You first need to know where the data is defined. If it is not defined by literal assignment in your code, then where is it? In an array? Coming from a JSON request? ... This needs to be clarified first..

Comment: I am just trying to create a new Car object without having to create a const Ford, const vauxhall every time I need one. This is not a real project, I am just trying to understand this way of creating objects using 'new'. Sorry if I am not explaining very clearly. I imagine someone entering 'toyota' and 'green' in html and being able to create a  'new Car' object. This is not possible in my current code because I would have to create 'const toyota = new Car("toyota", "green")'

Comment: OK, that is the clue I needed: you have a user entering the input in a HTML form.

Comment: Yes. Just want to use new Car variable as many times as required without having to hard code const each time. If possible. Can't think of a way to do this. I know there are other ways to achieve this but playing with 'new' keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want a user to determine the make and color of the car, possibly via HTML inputs.

Here is an example where a user can enter a make and a color and then have that car created. This car object is then added to an array, and the complete list of cars is iterated to call their `greet` method (which no longer outputs something, but returns it). That output is then combined on the page:

```js
function Car (make, color) {
    this.make = make;
    this.color = color;  
    this.greet = function () {
        // Don't output to console. Return it. It is up to caller 
        //    to decide what to do with this string
        return `The make is ${this.make} and color is ${this.color}`;
    };
}

const [makeInp, colorInp, createBtn, outElem] = 
    document.querySelectorAll("input, button, pre");

const allCars = []; // Array for cars that user will create

createBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const car = new Car(makeInp.value, colorInp.value);
    allCars.push(car); // Add the car to the collection
    // Clear the inputs:
    makeInp.value = "";
    colorInp.value = "";
    // Output all created car's greetings:
    outElem.textContent = allCars.map(car =>
        car.greet()
    ).join("\n"); // Each on a new line
});
```

```html
Make: <input><br>
Color: <input><br>
<button>Create Car</button><br>
Greeting(s): <pre></pre>
```

Comment: Cheers. I'll have a play with this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways of creating objects:

```
//Object Literal
let obj1 = {car: "Toyota"}

//Using Object Inbuilt Method
let obj2 = new Object();
obj2.car = "Toyota";

//Using Object.Create
let obj3 = Object.create();
obj3.car = "Toyota";

//Using a Constructor
function Car(name){
 this.car = name;
}
let obj4 = new Car("Toyota");
```

There is NO 5th way - and I don't think you can on the fly create any object you want. The best you close in is -- Object Literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Car class and define the setter method of "make" and "color".

```
class Car {
        constructor(make, color) {
            this.make = make;
            this.color = color;
        }
    
        set setMake(new_make) {
            this.make = new_make;
        }
        set setColor(new_color){
            this.color = new_color;
        }
        greet() {
            console.log(`The make is ${this.make} and color is ${this.color}`);
        }
    }

    let carObj = new Car("Ford","blue);
    carObj.greet();

    output: The make is Ford and color is blue
    
    carObj.setMake("Vauxhall");
    carObj.setColor("green");
    carObj.greet();
    
    output: The make is Vauxhall and color is green
```

Comment: But, is this object created on the fly or Dynamically? As Original-Poster had asked.

Comment: Thankyou

So I can't use:

const ford = new Car("Ford", "blue")
ford.greet();

and change ford dynamically